# Is it true that $\lim_{u\to 0}f\big(u,g(u)\big)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$. Let $g$ be a function defined on $D := (-\infty, -1) \cup \{0\} \cup (1, \infty)$.

Suppose that for all $u \in (0, \infty) \bigcap \left(\{0\} \cup (1, \infty) \right)$ we have $f(u, g(u)) = 16u^2$.

Is it true that $\lim_{u \to 0} f(u, g(u)) = 0$?

[Original statement of this question follows below.]

> I have a function $f$ defined on $(0;\infty[\times\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}^+:  (u,v)\to f(u,v)$. Let $g$ be a function defined on $D=]-\infty;-1)\cup \{0\}\cup (1;\infty[\to \Bbb{R}:v\to g(v)$
>
> For $\forall u\in(0;\infty[ \cap\Big( \{0\}\cup (1;\infty[ \Big)$ we have $f\big(u,g(u)\big)=16u^2$.
>
> My question can we say that $\lim_{u\to 0}f\big(u,g(u)\big)=0$
>
> Note that $(0;\infty[:=\{x\in\Bbb{R}, x>0\}$ and  $\Bbb{R}^+:=\{x\in\Bbb{R}, x\geq 0\}$

Comment: Please add something to the title

Comment: Gosh I find this so hard to read.

Comment: There is a *lot* to be said for the $(a, b)$ notation for an open interval, rather than $]a, b[$.

Comment: @Kacdima Does your $\mathbb{R}^+$ include $0$ or not? I just want to make the notation easier to read.

Comment: $(0;\infty[:=\{x\in\Bbb{R}, x>0\}$ and  $\Bbb{R}^+:=\{x\in\Bbb{R}, x\geq 0\}$

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm going to edit it so that it's more readable. I, and many people I know, really don't like the $]a, b[$ notation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the condition is equivalent to: for all $u > 1$ we have $f(u, g(u)) = 16u^2$.

Since we have no information about the behaviour of $z \mapsto f(z, g(z))$ near $z=0$, we can't say anything about its limit there.